# How do you detect gRPC server bind failure in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, grpc

In Python, when running `server.start()` if a port is unable to bind I get an error message on `stderr`---but no exception in Python.

How do we programmatically detect bind errors in gRPC servers in Python?

Example error message:

```
E1020 09:26:44.299467934    4160 server_chttp2.c:38]         {"created":"@1508506004.299423794","description":"No address added out of total 1 resolved","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/chttp2_server.c","file_line":245,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1508506004.299421071","description":"Failed to add any wildcard listeners","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_posix.c","file_line":338,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1508506004.299410944","description":"Unable to configure socket","fd":4,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.c","file_line":200,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1508506004.299407382","description":"OS Error","errno":98,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.c","file_line":173,"os_error":"Address already in use","syscall":"bind"}]},{"created":"@1508506004.299419953","description":"Unable to configure socket","fd":4,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.c","file_line":200,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1508506004.299417439","description":"OS Error","errno":98,"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_utils_posix_common.c","file_line":173,"os_error":"Address already in use","syscall":"bind"}]}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [the port number returned will be `0`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/c563b583cb9b7fecc33971581368796d2df4759d/include/grpc/grpc.h#L382-L386), but since you raise the question an exception would probably be better. [I've filed issue 13096 to make this more clear.](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13096)